# Confused making a quote generator and nothing returning from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So essentially as a first independent challenge after a couple days learning python. I decided on making a motivational quote generator where the user could input the type of motivation they require and the program would source an appropriate quote from one of the aptly named text files. So far, I have been trying to make this work for one of the motivational types and cannot seem to get past asking the user a question. I have no clue where I have gone wrong but obviously Im not great at this yet so could be making big mistakes! Any help is appreciated. As seen in the code below, I am taking an init function on a seperate python file called question to do prompts and answers. It is not resulting in anything being read or taken from the text files

```
from Question import Question

quote_type = input("What type of motivation do you need?\n(a) Work\n(b) Fitness\n(c) Financial\n(d) Life\n\n")
print(input(quote_type))


questions = [Question(quote_type[0], "")]


Work_Quo = open("Work_Quotes.txt", "r")

for Question in Question:
    answer = input(quote_type)
    if input == "a":
        import random
    def random_line(Work_Quo):
        lines = open(Work_Quo).read().splitlines()
        return random.choice(lines)
    print(random_line(Work_Quo))
```

Comment: `Work_Quo` is already a file object, so `open(Work_Quo)` doesn't look right.

Comment: `for Question in Question` also looks odd, especially if `Question` is a class.

Comment: You need to review how `input` function works in Python. Once you have saved the user's input in the variable `quote_type`, you don't need to use `input` again in the print statement, simply use the `quote_type` variable. Every time you are using `input` with (), you are actually asking the user to submit info again. It's a built-in function so use the variable in the if condition and not the function input.

Comment: @Chandral there are a lot of issues not necessarily with `input` function alone, I believe it is with undersetanding basic fundamentals of python language. For example indendation is something that would need to be reviewed by the OP. As indentation is crucial and key in python, more so than other languages such as JS for instance.

Comment: @rv.kvetch True, I was trying to address one at a time :)

Answer (score 1):

One issue I notice, is that `input()` is a builtin function in python.

Therefore, when you do:

```py
if input == "a":
```

This doesn't really make sense, as you're attempting to compare a function (type `callable`) to a string `str` type.

This would always be expected to fail, as the values can never be equal, if the underlying *types* of the things being compared are different to begin with.

For example, using intuition alone, would the following two things be equal?

```py
42 == '42'
```

The answer is a resounding "***nope***!" -- although this is not always the case in all languages, such as in JavaScript for example -- since python treats a number `42` as different from a string `"42"`.

My suggestion would be to use the variable `answer` you had defined here:

```py
answer = input(quote_type)
```

As such:

```py
if answer == "a":
```

There are, of course, other issues that are not immediately apparent.

For example, the following line of code has a glaring issue:

```py
    if input == "a":
        # here we import `random`, so `random` is only available within the scope of the `if` block
        import random
    # here is outside the `if` block, so the scope wouldn't have 
    # access to the `random` module!
    def random_line(Work_Quo):
        lines = open(Work_Quo).read().splitlines()
        return random.choice(lines)
    # this should fail, I think, because `random` is not available
    # if user input `answer != 'a'`
    print(random_line(Work_Quo))
```

The issue is with the conditional import (within `if` block):

```py
if input == "a":
    import random
```

Due to how indentation works in Python - essentially entering and exiting a block - along with a conditional import, what would happen at this line:

```py
if ...:
    import random

def random_line(Work_Quo):
    lines = open(Work_Quo).read().splitlines()
    # UH-OH!
    >> return random.choice(lines)
```

The code would be expected to break if the `if` condition is never satisfied, as the `random` module is not imported and available yet.

You can solve this by fixing the indentation, and hence changing the definition or scope of the lines following the `if` statement:

```
if ...:
    import random

    def random_line(Work_Quo):
        lines = open(Work_Quo).read().splitlines()
        # Works, because `random` is in scope of `random_line`!
        return random.choice(lines)
```

Comment: *"Due to how indentation works in Python - essentially entering and exiting a scope"* An `if` statement doesn't create a scope. Only class and function definitions really do that In Python.

Comment: *"The code would be expected to break if the if condition is never satisfied, as the random module is not imported and available yet."* <-- This is a correct explanation. It's about whether the import statement has already been executed, rather than a matter of scope.

Comment: @slothrop you are totally right bro... it has been some time since i've used python. I tried it out and you hit the nail on head... but I forgot about how scopes work in python, for some reason.

Comment: I’ll update answer shortly to fix that…